# Displaying generated PNG in PHP?

Tags: php, qr-code, barcode

So I'm trying to get a generated UPC bar code to display on an index page. but all it does is output the PNG contents instead of displaying the PNG itself.
I'm not quite sure why its doing this. I'm guessing its some silly little thing i need to add but I have no clue what it would be. So any help would be appreciated.

INDEX CODE

```
    <form method="POST">
<head>UPC Barcode and QRcode Generator</head><br>
<label for="">Type 11 Didgits Here => </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="text_code">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="generate">Generate</button>
<hr>
<?php
//QR CODE
if(isset($_POST['generate'])){
$code = $_POST['text_code'];
echo "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=$code&choe=UTF-8'>";}
//Barcode
include "generate.php";
$upc = new BC(null,4);
$number = $_POST['text_code'];
$upc->build($number);
echo "*".substr($code, 0,6)."#".substr($code, 6,6)."*";
?>
```

GENERATE CODE

```
<?php
class BC{//
    private $height;
    private $width;
    private $barheight;
    private $barwidth;
    private $lable;
    private $border;
    private $padding;
    private $mapcode;
    private $rightmap;
    private $code;
    function __construct($lable=null,$barwidth=2) {//
        $this->set_width($barwidth);
        $this->set_lable($lable);
        $this->padding = $barwidth*5;
        $this->border =2;
        $this->mapcode = array
        ('0' => '0001101', '1' => '0011001', '2' => '0010011', '3' => '0111101', '4' => '0100011',
         '5' => '0110001', '6' => '0101111', '7' => '0111011', '8' => '0110111', '9' => '0001011',
         '#' => '01010', '*' => '101');
        $this->rightmap = array
        ('0' => '1110010', '1' => '1100110', '2' => '1101100', '3' => '1000010', '4' => '1011100',
         '5' => '1001110', '6' => '1010000', '7' => '1000100', '8' => '1001000', '9' => '1110100',
         '#' => '01010', '*' => '101');
    }
public function set_width($barwidth) {//
        if(is_int($barwidth)) {//
            $this->barwidth = $barwidth;
        }
        else{//
            $this->barwidth = 2;
        }
    }
public function set_lable($lable) {//
        if(is_null($lable)) {//
            $this->lable = "none";
        }
        else{//
            $this->lable = $lable;
            }
        }
public function build($code = null) {//
        if(is_null($code)) {//
            $this->code = "00000000000";
        }
        else{//
            $this->code = $code;
            }

        $this-> code = substr($code, 0, 11);

        if(is_numeric($code)){//
            $checksum = 0;
            for($digit = 0; $digit < strlen($code); $digit++) {
                if($digit%2 == 0) {//
                    $checksum += (int)$code[$digit] * 3;
                }
                else{//
                    $checksum += (int) $code[$digit];
                }
            }
            $checkdigit = 10 - $checksum % 10;
            $code .= $checkdigit;
            $code_disp = $code;
            $code = "*".substr($code, 0,6)."#".substr($code, 6,6)."*";
            $this->width = $this-> barwidth*95 + $this->padding*2;
            $this->barheight = $this->barwidth*95*0.75;
            $this->height = $this->barwidth*95*0.75 + $this->padding*2;
            $barcode = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->barheight);
            $black = imagecolorallocate($barcode, 0, 0, 0);
            $white = imagecolorallocate($barcode, 255, 255, 255);
            imagefill($barcode, 0, 0, $black);
            imagefilledrectangle($barcode, $this->border, $this->width - $this->border, -1, $this->barheight - $this->border - 1, $white);
            $bar_pos = $this->padding;
            for($count = 0; $count < 15; $count++) {
                $character = $code [$count];
                for($subcount = 0; $subcount < strlen($this->mapcode[$character]); $subcount++) {//
                    if($count < 7) {
                        $color = ($this->mapcode[$character][$subcount] == 0) ? $white : $black;
                        }
                        else{
                        $color = ($this->rightmap[$character][$subcount] == 0) ? $white : $black;
                        }
                    if(strlen($this->mapcode[$character]) == 7) {
                        $height_offset = $this->height * 0.05;
                    }
                    else {
                        $height_offset = 0;
                        }
                        imagefilledrectangle($barcode, $bar_pos, $this->padding, $bar_pos+$this->barwidth - 1, $this->barheight - $height_offset - $this->padding, $color);
                        $bar_pos += $this->barwidth;
                        }
                        imagepng($barcode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

So this is the output

[image: It just displays in some weird text]

after adding the new code

[image: Here is the output now]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display an image in an HTML page, you need to use an `<img />` tag. To display image *contents* in an `<img />` tag, you need to use a [Data URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

You'll end up with something like this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,', base64_encode($the_png_contents), '" />';
```

Comment: Okay so i replaced "($the_png_contents)" with "($barcode)" and i still dont think its working

Comment: I mean now it just displays the broken image thing.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your Q and in the comments you said it still is not working so I decided to have a look with you. I used your code as you posted in and used it on my own little environment to make it work. What I did is the following:

Changed I made in your index.php:

```
// Check if request method is post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // Check if both Generate and Text_code have been set
    if(isset($_POST['generate']) && isset($_POST['text_code'])) {

        // Set code used through the if statement
        $code = $_POST['text_code'];
        echo '<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl='. $code . '&choe=UTF-8">';

        // Include file; generate.php
        include "generate.php";

        // New instance of class; BC
        $upc = new BC(null, 4);

        // Set barcode base64 to variable and display
        $barcodeBase64 = $upc->build($code);
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($barcodeBase64) . '" />';
    }
}
```

Furthermore your generate.php needed a little change in the function build:

```
public function build($code = null) {
    $this->code = is_null($code) ? "00000000000" : $code;

    $code = substr($code, 0, 11);
    $code = str_pad($code,  11, "00000000000");

    if(is_numeric($code)){//
        $checksum = 0;
        for($digit = 0; $digit < strlen($code); $digit++) {
            if($digit%2 == 0) {//
                $checksum += (int)$code[$digit] * 3;
            }
            else{//
                $checksum += (int) $code[$digit];
            }
        }
        $checkdigit = 10 - $checksum % 10;
        $code .= $checkdigit;
        $code_disp = $code;
        $code = "*".substr($code, 0,6)."#".substr($code, 6,6)."*";
        $this->width = $this-> barwidth*95 + $this->padding*2;
        $this->barheight = $this->barwidth*95*0.75;
        $this->height = $this->barwidth*95*0.75 + $this->padding*2;
        $barcode = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->barheight);
        $black = imagecolorallocate($barcode, 0, 0, 0);
        $white = imagecolorallocate($barcode, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($barcode, 0, 0, $black);
        imagefilledrectangle($barcode, $this->border, $this->width - $this->border, -1, $this->barheight - $this->border - 1, $white);
        $bar_pos = $this->padding;
        for($count = 0; $count < 15; $count++) {
            $character = $code[$count];
            for($subcount = 0; $subcount < strlen($this->mapcode[$character]); $subcount++) {//
                if($count < 7) {
                    $color = ($this->mapcode[$character][$subcount] == 0) ? $white : $black;
                }
                else{
                    $color = ($this->rightmap[$character][$subcount] == 0) ? $white : $black;
                }
                if(strlen($this->mapcode[$character]) == 7) {
                    $height_offset = $this->height * 0.05;
                }
                else {
                    $height_offset = 0;
                }
                imagefilledrectangle($barcode, $bar_pos, $this->padding, $bar_pos+$this->barwidth - 1, $this->barheight - $height_offset - $this->padding, $color);
                $bar_pos += $this->barwidth;
            }

        }

        ob_start();
        imagepng($barcode);
        $barcodeImage = ob_get_contents();
        ob_clean();

        return $barcodeImage;
    }
}
```

I also see that you filled the image with black which normally is filled with white as the code is a black on white image. To change this simply replace:

```
imagefill($barcode, 0, 0, $black); > imagefill($barcode, 0, 0, $white);
```